# CSV to MYsql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, delimiter

Please don't close this question, I know there are lots of solutions already buy none of them seem to work or at least isn't working for me. I've csv file from google affiliate network product feed, it comes in zip, .txt (csv) tab delimiter. I've so far unziped file and read file, but what I want to do is dump that data to mysql database, 1st row of csv are headers, I want to create field names according to csv file and put data in database respectively, some fields in csv file are empty. I also want capability to run it again (possibly I'll run cron job for that) and insert only new data in there.
example of my csv file:

```
ProductID   ProductName ProductURL  BuyURL  ImageURL    Category    CategoryID  PFXCategory BriefDesc   ShortDesc   IntermDesc  LongDesc    ProductKeyword  Brand   Manufacturer    ManfID  ManufacturerModel   UPC Platform    MediaTypeDesc   MerchandiseType Price   SalePrice   VariableCommission  SubFeedID   InStock Inventory   RemoveDate  RewPoints   PartnerSpecific ShipAvail   ShipCost    ShippingIsAbsolut   ShippingWeight  ShipNeeds   ShipPromoText   ProductPromoText    DailySpecialsInd    GiftBoxing  GiftWrapping    GiftMessaging   ProductContainerName    CrossSellRef    AltImagePrompt  AltImageURL AgeRangeMin AgeRangeMax ISBN    Title   Publisher   Author  Genre   Media   Material    PermuColor  PermuSize   PermuWeight PermuItemPrice  PermuSalePrice  PermuInventorySta   Permutation PermutationSKU  BaseProductID   Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4 Option5 Option6 Option7 Option8 Option9 Option10    Option11    Option12    Option13    Option14    Option15    Option16    Option17    Option18    Option19    Option20    
4181615950845mkTWIN~TWIN    Brylanehome Jasmine Quilt Set (Sea Green,Twin)  http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_click?lid=41000613802463546&pid=4181615950845mkTWIN~TWIN&adurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brylanehome.com%2FProduct.aspx%3FPfId%3D20653%26ProductTypeId%3D2%26affiliate_id%3D017%26mr%3AtrackingCode%3D8C875316-BB51-E211-9A4A-90E2BA0278A8%26mr%3AreferralID%3DNA&usg=AFHzDLtiRj_wSyAQFEPxMBFVo4HjTeHMVA&pubid=21000000000568460  http://gan.doubleclick.net/gan_click?lid=41000613802463546&pid=4181615950845mkTWIN~TWIN&adurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brylanehome.com%2FProduct.aspx%3FPfId%3D20653%26ProductTypeId%3D2%26affiliate_id%3D017%26mr%3AtrackingCode%3D8C875316-BB51-E211-9A4A-90E2BA0278A8%26mr%3AreferralID%3DNA&usg=AFHzDLtiRj_wSyAQFEPxMBFVo4HjTeHMVA&pubid=21000000000568460  http://media.redcatsecom.com/brylanehome/mc/1595_41816_mc_0845.jpg?wid=230&hei=331&qlt=95&op_sharpen=1  Bedding > Quilts            Picture perfect on any bed, this pieced and stitched quilt set is the ideal choice for spring bedding. &#160; &#8226; A BrylaneHome&#174; Exclusive!&#160; &#8226; all-over floral print quilt reverses to a stripe &#8226; scalloped edges &#8226; 100% cotton         Picture perfect on any bed, this pieced and stitched quilt set is the ideal choice for spring bedding. &#160; &#8226; A BrylaneHome&#174; Exclusive!&#160; &#8226; all-over floral print quilt reverses to a stripe &#8226; scalloped edges &#8226; 100% cotton face/cotton/poly fill &#8226; available in 3 sizes: Twin 2-Pc. Set 68" x 90", Full/Queen 3-Pc. 86" x 86", and King 3-Pc. 100" x 90" &#8226; machine wash/dry &#8226; imported &#8226; pair this quilt with any of our colorful and elegant sheets to create a dynamic layered look &#8226; and shop our selection of total bed sets to reinvent your d&#233;cor overnight &#160; This vibrant quilt set includes: 1 quilt and 2 standard shams (1 with twin).&#160; &#160; Why Buy?&#160; Our customers agree that our patchwork bedding shows off their vibrant and fun d&#233;cors while offering them incredible comfort at great values.&#160;      BrylaneHome Brylane Home        4181615950845mkTWIN~TWIN                new 114.99  59.99           in stock    47                                                                          adult           Brylanehome Jasmine Quilt Set (Sea Green,Twin)                      SEA GREEN   TWIN                                                                                            Home & Garden > Linens & Bedding > Bedding > Quilts & Quilt Sets    4181615950845mkTWIN~TWIN        1595-41816
```

Script I used to unzip:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;     
    $res = $zip->open('K9349.zip');
    if ($res === TRUE) {
     $zip->extractTo('extracted/');
     $zip->close();
     echo 'Unzip was successful';
     } else {
     echo 'Unzip was not successful';
}
?>
```

Below are two scripts that I tried without any luck.
script 1:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("extracted/K9349.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

script 2:

```
<?php

$host = '****';
$user = '****';
$pass = '****';
$database = '****';

$db = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_query("use $database", $db);

/********************************************************************************/
// Parameters: filename.csv table_name
$file = 'extracted/K9349.txt';
$argv = $_SERVER[argv];

if($argv[1]) { $file = $argv[1]; }
else {
    echo "Please provide a file name\n"; exit; 
}
if($argv[2]) { $table = $argv[2]; }
else {
    $table = pathinfo($file);
    $table = $table['filename'];
}

/********************************************************************************/
// Get the first row to create the column headings

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$frow = fgetcsv($fp);

$ccount = 0;
foreach($frow as $column) {
    $ccount++;
    if($columns) $columns .= ', ';
    $columns .= "$column varchar(250)";
}

$create = "create table if not exists $table ($columns);";
mysql_query($create, $db);

/********************************************************************************/
// Import the data into the newly created table.

$file = $_SERVER['PWD'].'/'.$file;
$q = "load data infile '$file' into table $table fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines";
mysql_query($q, $db);

?>
```

I'll be really thankful if you can help.

Comment: If your CSV file is tab delimited why are using `,` as delimiter in script 1. Try using `while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE)`.

Comment: script 1 is at no use, I've done it is just funny output there, even if it's not funny how can I send this data to database table. here is output for [script1](http://www.lostknowledge.org/google/readcsv.php) it's just not reading it right because there are six thoudans some record in csv file. here is output for [script2](http://www.lostknowledge.org/google/savedata.php) here is the csv [file](http://www.lostknowledge.org/google/extracted/K9349.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following script. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$dbconn = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");
$importedCSVFile = "filename.csv";
$row_data = array();
if(($handle = fopen($importedCSVFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $rowCounter = 0;
    while(($row_data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        if(0 == $rowCounter) {
            $create_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (";
            foreach($row_data as $column) {
                $create_query .= $column." VARCHAR(250), ";
            }
            $create_query = rtrim($create_query, ",").")";
            mysqli_query($dbconn, $create_query);
        } 
        else {
            $q_string = "";
            foreach($row_data as $key => $value) {
                $q_string = '"'.$value.'",';
            }
            mysqli_query($dbconn, 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('.rtrim($q_string, ",").')');
        }
        $rowCounter++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: [click here to see errors](http://www.lostknowledge.org/google/onemore.php) ok here are the errors error one: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock' (1) in /homepages/15/d412900185/htdocs/lostknowledge.org/google/onemore.php on line 3 then error for every record i guess Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /homepages/15/d412900185/htdocs/lostknowledge.org/google/onemore.php on line 15

Comment: I tried to change mysqli with mysql, it'll solve connect problem but everthing else reamins same

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file from google affiliate network product feed is probably always in the same format. so it might be simpler to create a table manually and then just import the file with a cron job.